# I can't update entry for a particular document in my MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The function reads everything from the database but I can't change the value of the "hasVoted" field in my Voters model in the database.

I want to change the value from false to true. After setting data.hasVoted = true, I tried *console.log(data.hasVoted)* and it returns true but when I checked my database the value was still false.

```js
req.app.db.models.Voter.findOne({ cnic: req.body.cnic }, function(err, data) {
  if (
    data.name == req.body.name &&
    data.cnic == req.body.cnic &&
    data.voterid == req.body.voterid &&
    data.hasVoted == false
  ) {
    data.hasVoted = true;

    var voteUrl = "/votingpage";

    var votePayload = {
      name: req.body.name,
      cnic: req.body.cnic,
      voterid: req.body.voterid,
      constituency: data.constituency
    };

    req.app.db.models.Voter.updateOne(
      { cnic: votePayload.cnic },
      { $set: { hasVoted: true } }
    );

    res.cookie("votePayload", votePayload);
    data.hasVoted = true;
    console.log(data.hasVoted);
    //return res.redirect(voteUrl);
  } else {
    res.redirect("/Votenotallowed");
  }
});
```

Comment: I also tried this but it had no effect: 
`req.app.db.models.Voter.updateOne({"cnic":votePayload.cnic},{$set:{hasVoted:true}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the below code.

```
req.app.db.models.Voter.findOne({ "cnic": req.body.cnic }, function (err, data) {
    if (data.name == req.body.name && data.cnic == req.body.cnic && data.voterid == req.body.voterid && data.hasVoted == false) {
        data.hasVoted = true;
        var voteUrl = '/votingpage';
        var votePayload = {
            name: req.body.name,
            cnic: req.body.cnic,
            voterid: req.body.voterid,
            constituency: data.constituency
        }

        req.app.db.models.Voter.updateOne({ "cnic": votePayload.cnic }, { $set: { hasVoted: true } }, { upsert: true, new: true }).exec((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500)
            } else {
                res.cookie('votePayload', votePayload);
                data.hasVoted = true;
                console.log(data.hasVoted);
                //return res.redirect(voteUrl);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/Votenotallowed')
    }
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it providing options in query

```
    req.app.db.models.Voter.updateOne({"cnic":votePayload.cnic},{$set:{hasVoted:true}} , {upsert: true , new: true}).exec((err , updatedLog)=>{
     if(err){
      console.log(err);
     }
     else{
       console.log(updatedLog);
     }

   });
```